# How to determine status of upstart job in bash script?

Tags: bash, upstart

How do you determine if an upstart job is running inside of a Bash script?  That is I need a "boolean" value to do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ determine_if_job_x_is_running ]; then
  echo "I see upstart job X is running, please stop it before ..."
fi
```

Answer (score 9):

Create your own Bash function and put this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
check_upstart_service(){
    status $1 | grep -q "^$1 start" > /dev/null
    return $?
}
```

I really dislike the way of parsing output, but I don't see another obvious way. And in this case the output of `<service name> start` is very reliable as it's specified in [the Upstart documentation](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html).

Now you can use it like this:

```
if check_upstart_service ssh; then echo "running"; else echo "stopped"; fi
```

Comment: You might want to amend this to `status $1 2> /dev/null | grep -q "^$1 start" > /dev/null 2> /dev/null` just to make sure it's silent.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you use a PID file but you can also use pgrep to check your processes. Assume your service is called `jobX` this will work:

```
if [ $(pgrep jobX) ]; then
```

Or even better

```
if pgrep jobX > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [String contains in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/229606):

```
job='your_job_name'
job_status=$(status ${job})
if [[ ${job_status} == *running* ]]
  then
    # do whatever you need
  else
    # do whatever you need
fi
```

My first impulse was to use variation of code ImaginaryRobots provided

```
job='your_job_name'
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=com.ubuntu.Upstart \
  /com/ubuntu/Upstart/jobs/${job}/_ \
  org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:'' string:state
```

which would return something like

> method return sender=:1.0 -> dest=:1.94 reply_serial=2
>     variant       string "running"

and use the solution above to check if the returned string contains "running". However case that job is not running dbus call will exit with status 1 instead returning "waiting" as I was expecting.

`status ${job}` would never exit with status 1 except in the case when there is no such job.

Comment: A variation ...  isRunning=$(status ${job} | grep running | wc -l)  will return 1 if it is running and 0 if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

You would use DBUS to query the status of that particular service.

```
$ job=myjob
$ dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=com.ubuntu.Upstart /com/ubuntu/Upstart/jobs/${job}/_ org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll string:''
```

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#get-status-of-job-via-d-bus

Note that if you're writing your own upstart job, you should use upstart events or package dependencies instead.

Comment: Seems like this would just print some sort of text status that you would then have to parse to get a boolean value, right?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the upstart status command conforms to the init script specification from the Linux Standard Base project, meaning that you can assume an exit code of 0 means the program is running, an exit code of 1-3 means it is running, and any other exit code means an undefined status.

See:
http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-PDA/LSB-PDA/iniscrptact.html